# How can I more efficiently multiply every element in a batch of tensors with every other batch element, except for itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, autograd

So, I have this code that multiplies every element in a batch of tensors with every other element, except for itself. The code works, but it becomes painfully slow with larger batch sizes (Ideally I want to be able to use it with batch sizes of up to 1000 or more, but even a couple hundred is okay). It basically freezes when using the PyTorch autograd system and large batch sizes (like 50 or greater).

I need help making the code faster and more efficient, while still getting the same output. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import torch

tensor = torch.randn(50, 512, 512)

batch_size = tensor.size(0)
list1 = []
for i in range(batch_size):
    list2 = []
    for j in range(batch_size):
        if j != i:
            x_out = (tensor[i] * tensor[j]).sum()
            list2.append(x_out )
    list1.append(sum(list2))

out = sum(list1)
```

I thought that `torch.prod` might be able to be used, but it doesn't seem to result in the same output as the code above. NumPy answers are acceptable as long as they can be recreated in PyTorch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import torch
tensor = torch.randn(50, 512, 512)

batch_size = tensor.size(0)
tensor = tensor.reshape(batch_size, -1)
prod = torch.matmul(tensor, tensor.transpose(0,1))
out = torch.sum(prod) - torch.trace(prod)
```

Here, you first flatten each element. Then, you multiply the matrix where each row is an element with its own transpose, which gives a `batch_size x batch_size` matrix, where the `ij`th element equals the product of `tensor[i]` with `tensor[j]`. So, summing up over the values in this matrix and subtracting its trace (i.e., sum of diagonal elements) gives the desired result.

I tried both methods with a `batch_size` of 1000, and the time taken dropped from 61.43s to 0.59s.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I just tried your code and it seems to round the output to a whole number, while the original code has a decimal value in addition to the whole number. This might be an accuracy issue for my code, but I'm not 100% as to the reason why it happens with your code? Or maybe it's a complete non-issue?

Comment: @ProGamerGov Yes, I see that as well. I got exact results with small fixed tensors, and values for other cases were close enough that I assumed it to be an issue of precision. But I am not sure of the cause, it may need further investigation.

Comment: @ProGamerGov It seems to be a precision issue. Changing the initialization of `tensor` to  `tensor = torch.randn(50,512,512,dtype=torch.float64)` fixed it. If your use case requires only `float32`, then the error is probably not significant, I think.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for figuring out the issue!